# Create array of images from array of objects in WCF web service

Tags: c#, arrays, wcf

I have a 2D array of chairs like this: `chairs[][]` also here is my chair class:

```
public class Chair
{
    public int State;
    public int number;
}
```

Each object of class represent a seat in a theater (state indicates the seat status; 0 means empty, 1 means reserved and number indicates the seat number).

Let's assume that I have these values:

```
    0   0   0   1
    1   1   1   0
    0   1   0   1
```

I want to create array of images like this:

[image]

and finally convert it to array of bytes and return it as web service output. **long story short i want to convert array of `chair[][]` to the images. my web service input will be `chairs[][]` and output will be `byte[]`.**

Is this possible?

**UPDATE**:

here i created something in windows desktop application. i just need create it in wcf. i have now idea how can create `Picturebox` or `Labal` in wcf!!!

```
{
    AutoScroll = true;
    int x = 10, y = 10;

    Chair[][] chairs = new Chair[3][];
    chairs[0] = new Chair[4] { new Chair { number = 1, State = 0 }, new Chair { number = 2, State = 0 }, new Chair { number = 3, State = 0 }, new Chair { number = 4, State = 1 } };
    chairs[1] = new Chair[4] { new Chair { number = 5, State = 1 }, new Chair { number = 6, State = 1 }, new Chair { number = 7, State = 1 }, new Chair { number = 8, State = 0 } };
    chairs[2] = new Chair[4] { new Chair { number = 9, State = 0 }, new Chair { number = 10, State = 1 }, new Chair { number = 11, State = 0 }, new Chair { number = 12, State = 1 } };

    Label[][] label = new Label[chairs.Length][];
    PictureBox[][] picturebox = new PictureBox[chairs.Length][];

    for (int i = 0; i < chairs.Length; i++)
    {
        label[i] = new Label[chairs[i].Length];
        picturebox[i] = new PictureBox[chairs[i].Length];


        for (int j = 0; j < chairs[i].Length; j++)
        {
            label[i][j] = new Label();
            picturebox[i][j] = new PictureBox();

            Controls.Add(label[i][j]);
            Controls.Add(picturebox[i][j]);

            label[i][j].Location = new Point(x, y + 50);
            picturebox[i][j].Location = new Point(x, y);

            label[i][j].Size = new Size(100, 20);
            picturebox[i][j].Size = new Size(50, 50);

            label[i][j].Text = i + "*" + j + "(" + chairs[i][j].number + ")";
            if (chairs[i][j].State == 0) picturebox[i][j].Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\1\1.png");
            else picturebox[i][j].Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\1\2.png");

            x = x + 100;
        }
        x = 10;
        y = y + 100;
    }
```

Comment: Is it ok for you if chairs are serialized over the network, being passed to a web service or returned from a web service ?

Comment: dear @Emmanuel honestly i didn't get it what you asking. but long story short i want convert array of class to the images. my web service input is chairs[][] and output is byte[]. i hope i could explain it.

Comment: You can edit and remove the sentence about silly questions (they don't exist). But it 's important that we understand ! What do you expect to be in the byte [] ?  ... Some png picture ... ?

Comment: done :). let me put it this way: i have a string of 0101... and i want to create array of images from 01 string. if string[i]=0 replace it with image1.png else replace it with image2.png. Ive also done it in a windows form application. so sorry. I'm doing my best to explain it but its really hard to explain.

Comment: if I understand well you want to receive the image in PNG format as a byte[] - a single image for all the theater, right ?

Comment: no. i want receive a 0101 string and convert it to the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string firstText = "Hello";
string secondText = "World";

PointF firstLocation = new PointF(10f, 10f);
PointF secondLocation = new PointF(10f, 50f);

string imageFilePath = @"path\picture.bmp"
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(imageFilePath);//load the image file

using(Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
{
   using (Font arialFont =  new Font("Arial", 10))
   {
       graphics.DrawString(firstText, arialFont,Brushes.Blue,firstLocation);
       graphics.DrawString(secondText,arialFont,Brushes.Red,secondLocation);
    }
}

bitmap.Save(imageFilePath);//save the image
```

Comment: Try this, u can create 2 templates - with "R" end empty Chair, leave the place for numbers empty and try this code

Comment: thank you. its sort of my answer. but how can put array of this images in one image? like my image in my question?

Comment: u can just create a big empty image/bitmap with height = sum of heigths of your array images in one column(for e.g. 3 rows in column with each image height = 200 pixels, so big image height = 3*200 = 600 and do the same with width) then just use Graphics class to draw each of yours images on this bitmap

Answer (score 1):

First - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms734712(v=vs.100).aspx

then

```
// Service side
[ServiceContract(Name = "chairs-image-generator")]
public interface IChairsImageArrayGenerator
{
    // insted byte[] paste desirable type of image
    [OperationContract(Name = "generate-images")]
    IEnumerable<byte[]> GenerateImage(IEnumerable<byte[][]> chairs);
}

// Client side
[ServiceContract(Name = "chairs-image-generator")]
public interface IChairsImageArrayGeneratorClient
{
    [OperationContract(Name = "generate-images")]
    IEnumerable<byte[]> GenerateImages(IEnumerable<byte[][]> chairs);
}

public class ChairsImageGenerator : IChairsImageArrayGenerator
{
    public IEnumerable<byte[]> GenerateImages(IEnumerable<byte[][]> chairs)
    {
        // put here your realization 
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you dear @android_dev_123. but its not what i want!! i guess i clearly explained what exactly i want.

Comment: tell me more exactly what troubles u have - 1) creating a WCF service 2) creating an image from Chair class? or with smth else?

Comment: thank you so much,  creating an image from Chair class is my concern.